# Microsoft graph c# sdk how to assign user to application

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Microsoft. Graph -Version 1.15.0 SDK with.Net core application, not able to find any method using which I can assign the application to the user which I have created.
I am aware with Graph API to assign the application to the user, but looking to SDK implementation for same.
I have tried to look on Github documentation but all are with Graph API I am looking with SDK
graphClient.Users["userId"].App?
Microsoft.Graph SDK method to assign the application to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use below method to add application user using graph sdk

```
 public Microsoft.Graph.IUserManagedAppRegistrationsCollectionWithReferencesPage ManagedAppRegistrations { get; set; }
        Member of Microsoft.Graph.User

Summary:
Gets or sets managed app registrations. Zero or more managed app registrations that belong to the user.
```

from object browser, you can take a look of all the available operations in user entity

[image]

Hope it helps.